# Me gustaría saber sobre este programa para poder hacer otros parecidos

Tags: c, windows

Estoy estudiando Sistemas Operativos y mi profesor nos mandó estos programas en
C solo para analizarlos pero realmente no sé que es lo que hacen, lo único que
entiendo es que son para uso de memoria compartida, ¿podría alguien solamente
explicármelo ,por favor?

**Programa 1:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h> /* Cliente de la memoria compartida */

#define TAM_MEM 27   /*Tamaño de la memoria compartida en bytes */

int main(void) {
  HANDLE hArchMapeo;
  char *idMemCompartida = "MemoriaCompatida";
  char *apDatos, *apTrabajo, c;
  if ((hArchMapeo = OpenFileMapping(
           FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // acceso lectura/escritura de la memoria
                                // compartida
           FALSE,               // no se hereda el nombre
           idMemCompartida)     // identificador de la memoria compartida
       ) == NULL) {
    printf("No se abrio archivo de mapeo de la memoria compartida: (%i)\n",
           GetLastError());
    exit(-1);
  }
  if ((apDatos = (char *)MapViewOfFile(
           hArchMapeo,          // Manejador del mapeo
           FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // Permiso de lectura/escritura en la memoria
           0, 0, TAM_MEM)) == NULL) {
    printf("No se accedio a la memoria compartida: (%i)\n", GetLastError());
    CloseHandle(hArchMapeo);
    exit(-1);
  }
  for (apTrabajo = apDatos; *apTrabajo != '\0'; apTrabajo++)
    putchar(*apTrabajo);
  putchar('\n');
  *apDatos = '*';
  UnmapViewOfFile(apDatos);
  CloseHandle(hArchMapeo);
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: El bucle for no tiene llave, por tanto sólo el primer `putchar` debería estar identado (es una muy mala práctica, por otro lado).

Comment: Explioca linea a linea que piensas lo que hace, y luego de eso, podemos darte una respuesta.

Comment: Listo, son las líneas de código que mas o menos sé lo que realizan